# How to declare many-to-many relationships if the join table is in a different database?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

For example, posts table is in db1, categories table and category_post_join table are in db2. How to declare a many-to-many relationship between Post model and Category model?

```
'categories'=>array(self::MANY MANY, 'Category', 'category_post_join (post_id, category_id)')
```

works only if all tables are in the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. The CActiveRecord functionality is based on a physical PDO connection, which is linked to a specific database. There is no support for doing a join across multiple database that I know of. I actually ran into the same problem a while ago and had to work around it.

I really hope there is a possible answer here, but I haven't found one so far.

Comment: I prefixed the join-table name with database name (e.g., db2.category_post_join). It works for some cases.

Comment: Yeah I guess that could work if the permissions and so on are correct. Given what Yii does with the queries and so on, I just didn't really feel comfortable doing that. Thanks for the feedback.